# Java clone only superclass

Tags: java, serialization, cloning

I have such a question: is it possible some how to "extract" superclass from one object to new object? I'll show what I mean.

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    subclass sb = new subclass(false);
    System.out.println(sb.a);
    System.out.println(sb.b);
    superclass sc = sb;
    superclass sc2;
    try {

        sc2 = sc.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(((subclass)sc2).a);
}

private static class superclass implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    public boolean b;
    public superclass() {
        b = false;
    }
    public superclass(boolean a) {
        this.b = a;
    }
    public superclass clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (superclass)super.clone();
    }
}

private static class subclass extends superclass implements Serializable{
    public boolean a;
    public subclass(boolean a) {
        super(true);
        this.a = a;
    }
}
}
```

with this code I'm getting this output:

```
false
true
false
```

which means that object was cloned totally, bu I want to clone only superclass.

Is it any already implemented way to do this or I have to implement my own field-to-field copy method in superclass?

Comment: Why would you want to partially clone an object? This would break `clone()`'s contract. If you only want to copy part of an object, I strongly suggest you consider using a factory method or a copy contructor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you really trying to achive/prove by the example. Even if it was possible to clone only superclass, the result would still remain the same as it would simply just copy the `a` field.

Anyway, the answer is no. The clone is method by purpose so you don't need to care about the real class in the background. If you wished to do partial clone for specific super class you could easily achieve this by calling specific constructor/setters as you have all the information in compile time.